# Will PC3-12800R RAM work with an Intel DH61CR motherboard?

Tags: memory, motherboard, desktop-computer

I've found two sticks of 8GB PC3-12800R RAM I'd like to buy for my custom PC (not my main PC, my main PC is an Acer Extensa 2511) for my birthday this year to max out my custom PC's RAM to 16GB for the lowest possible cost, but I'm unsure if PC3-12800R RAM works with my custom PC's motherboard, an Intel DH61CR. Would the 8GB PC3-12800R RAM work with the Intel DH61CR motherboard, and if so, how well?

Answer (score 0):

PC3-12800R is equivalent to DDR-1600, which your motherboards [datasheet](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/51857/intel-desktop-board-dh61cr.html) says is compatible.